# std::vector randomly adds elements to vector

Tags: c++, random, vector, std, c++14

I am sorting points, the code that I wrote for the sorting part works perfectly, but I have one issue. Every so often (at random times) random points are added to the end of the vector, and when I try to pop_back() to delete these last elements (because I wrote a small portion to check to make sure the number of points are the same), I end up in an infinite loop trying to delete these last elements, which just won't go away. Is there something I should know? Also some of the points randomly disappear even when I do not try to delete them. I am trying to understand what I need to exactly do to prevent these weird points from poping up, because these points are sorted in a specific order.

I only have three insert methods, and the first is an emplace_back(), the next is an insert, and the last is also an insert method:

```
                if (afterX >= spheres.capacity())
                    spheres.emplace_back(center);
                else if(afterX == -1)
                    spheres.insert(spheres.begin(),center);
                else
                    spheres.insert(std::next( spheres.begin(), afterX ),center);
                elementCount++;
```

Here is my output, to get an idea:

```
Point: <5,0,0>
zFind: -1
<5,0,0>
Point: <10,0,0>
zFind: 0
yFind: 0
<5,0,0><10,0,0>
Point: <100,0,0>
zFind: 0
yFind: 0
<5,0,0><10,0,0><100,0,0><2.11207e-023,0,0>
Point: <30,0,0>
zFind: 0
yFind: 0
<5,0,0><10,0,0><30,0,0><100,0,0>
Point: <20,0,0>
zFind: 0
yFind: 0
<5,0,0><10,0,0><20,0,0><30,0,0><100,0,0><2.10934e-023,2.21351e+033,0><0,0,2.21351e+033><0,0,0>
```

As you can see the point: Point is added correctly in the series (least to greatest), but these are odd extra numbers at the end that are there and then disappear.

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: Most likely, inserting and removing elements from a vector invalidates all existing iterators. But without seeing code, it will be difficult to give a real answer.

Comment: Simply push back the elements and post sort. Simplifies your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `capacity` where you should be using `size`.  `capacity` returns the number of *allocated* elements in the vector, which can be larger than the number of elements stored in the vector (which is the `size`).  Accessing elements past the end of `size` is undefined behavior

When you add an element to a vector where `size() == capacity()`, new memory will be allocated to hold the entire vector (from what you're showing above, your implementation is doubling the capacity when it needs to do this).  The old content is copied to the new memory, and the new element added in.

The odd extra numbers are what is just what happens to be sitting in the uninitialized memory that was allocated for the new content.

In the normal course of using a `vector` you rarely if ever need to access the `capacity`.